# Set only one DataGrid Row to be editable programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I am filling up my DataGrid with information from a database. The information is appearing fine. I want to keep everything as read only less one column. I do not want that column header to be editable. Only the rows that come under it. for example as per the image below, I want to be able to edit the column Participants row content 5,5,5 and 3.

I don't see any options to be able individually select a row or column to set as read only. I only see an option to set the entire DataGrid as read only. I was trying to loop through and attempt to set read only to the desired column but couldn't. Please advice. Thanks.

[image]

Saw some examples where you can individually state which column to be readonly via XAML but those were manual inputs for pre-determined data. I am trying to fill the DataGrid using Auto generated columns and data is coming from a database and I want to do it programmatically.

```
Connection connection = new Connection();
public static DataTable dt = new DataTable();

private void FillTable(DataGrid dataGrid)
{
    //Connecting to database
    connection.ConnectToDB(table, dt);
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

    foreach (DataGridColumn column in dataGrid1.Columns)
    {
        if (column.DisplayIndex == 1)
        {
            dataGrid1.IsReadOnly = true;
        }              
    }

    //dataGrid1.IsReadOnly = true;
}
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid1" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Height="auto" Width="auto" MaxHeight="400" AutoGenerateColumns="True" Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle1}"/>
```

Comment: Are columns auto generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If columns are auto generated then handle `DataGrid.AutoGeneratingColumn`.

```
private void OnAutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName != "Participants")
    { e.Column.IsReadOnly = true; }
}
```

And change `FillTable` method:

```
private void FillTable(DataGrid dataGrid)
{
    connection.ConnectToDB(table, dt);
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

Comment: Tried your method. Every column ends up being editable and when I try to edit the Participants row content and press enter, the screen freezes.

Comment: Edited and added my XAML line for the datagrid if it helps.

Comment: Remove `dataGrid1.IsReadOnly = true;` from your code.

Comment: Yes I'm using your code with the edited FillTable method as you've shown.

Comment: Minor correction. The screen freezing was my fault. I entered incorrect value. The error is  - I can edit everything, not just the Participant column.

Comment: It works when I edit my dataGrid XAML and add the following. AutoGeneratingColumn="OnAutoGeneratingColumn"

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoGenerateColumns`-Property to false, than you can provide the properties you want in the visual-design you want.

Small example with skinning:

```
<GroupBox Grid.Row="2" Header="Items" Padding="5">
    <GroupBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
            <Style.Resources>
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#C2E58F" />
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C2E58F" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Style.Resources>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
            <Setter Property="AutoGenerateColumns" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="AlternationCount" Value="2" />
            <Setter Property="AlternatingRowBackground" Value="LightGray" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserAddRows" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="CanUserDeleteRows" Value="False" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionMode" Value="Single" />
            <Setter Property="SelectionUnit" Value="FullRow" />
            <Setter Property="FocusManager.IsFocusScope" Value="True" />
        </Style>
    </GroupBox.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding NameNotes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Firstname" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="Firstname">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Firstname}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding Firstname}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Lastname" Width="Auto" SortMemberPath="Lastname">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Lastname}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Note" Width="*" SortMemberPath="Note">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Note}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,1" TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</GroupBox>
```

To edit one column you have to provide a `CellEditingTemplate` for this column. I've done this for the Firstname-Column in my example.

Comment: Thanks but was trying to do it from my class file programmatic ally without XAML preferably.